# Is there some lock on Firefox cookies.sqlite file even when Firefox is not open?

Tags: c#, firefox, cookies, system.data.sqlite

I am using System.Data.SQLite in C# to try and write a cookie for firefox however when I try to open a connection I get an exception saying "Unable to open database file" with an error code of 14.

If I copy the cookies.sqlite file and move it elsewhere however, I can access it without any issues, so, is there some lock mechanism in place even when firefox is not open?

```
var strPath = Environment.GetFolderPath(Environment.SpecialFolder.ApplicationData) + @"\Mozilla\Profiles\qhy0pdxy.default-release\cookies.sqlite";

var strDb = "Data Source=" + strPath;

SQLiteConnection conn = new SQLiteConnection(strDb);

conn.Open();
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One way of getting around this is to just copy the file, perform the insert and then overwrite the original. Not the best but it works...